# Realizar Operações Estatísticas em um Arquivo CSV

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa para realizar algumas operações matemáticas dentro de um arquivo CSV, porém não gostaria de usar o pandas, queria fazer através de dicionário. Segue o código que estou fazendo para realizar a função de soma.

```
import csv

soma_public = ['1930', '1950', '1970', '1990', '2010']
with open('WorldCups.csv') as csv_file:
    soma = sum(int(vals[2]) for vals in csv.reader(csv_file) if vals[0] in soma_public)
print(soma)
```

Este são os dados do meu CSV:

```
Year,Country,Winner,Runners-Up,Third,Fourth,GoalsScored,QualifiedTeams,MatchesPlayed,Attendance
1930,Uruguay,Uruguay,Argentina,USA,Yugoslavia,70,13,18,590.549
1934,Italy,Italy,Czechoslovakia,Germany,Austria,70,16,17,363.000
1938,France,Italy,Hungary,Brazil,Sweden,84,15,18,375.700
1950,Brazil,Uruguay,Brazil,Sweden,Spain,88,13,22,1.045.246
1954,Switzerland,Germany FR,Hungary,Austria,Uruguay,140,16,26,768.607
1958,Sweden,Brazil,Sweden,France,Germany FR,126,16,35,819.810
1962,Chile,Brazil,Czechoslovakia,Chile,Yugoslavia,89,16,32,893.172
1966,England,England,Germany FR,Portugal,Soviet Union,89,16,32,1.563.135
1970,Mexico,Brazil,Italy,Germany FR,Uruguay,95,16,32,1.603.975
1974,Germany,Germany FR,Netherlands,Poland,Brazil,97,16,38,1.865.753
1978,Argentina,Argentina,Netherlands,Brazil,Italy,102,16,38,1.545.791
1982,Spain,Italy,Germany FR,Poland,France,146,24,52,2.109.723
1986,Mexico,Argentina,Germany FR,France,Belgium,132,24,52,2.394.031
1990,Italy,Germany FR,Argentina,Italy,England,115,24,52,2.516.215
1994,USA,Brazil,Italy,Sweden,Bulgaria,141,24,52,3.587.538
1998,France,France,Brazil,Croatia,Netherlands,171,32,64,2.785.100
2002,Korea/Japan,Brazil,Germany,Turkey,Korea Republic,161,32,64,2.705.197
2006,Germany,Italy,France,Germany,Portugal,147,32,64,3.359.439
2010,South Africa,Spain,Netherlands,Germany,Uruguay,145,32,64,3.178.856
2014,Brazil,Germany,Argentina,Netherlands,Brazil,171,32,64,3.386.810
```

**Estou precisando fazer as seguintes operações:**
Soma de público das copas com anos final 0 (1930, 1950, etc)
Quantidade total de gols entre as copas de 1954 e 1990, inclusive
Média de público
Média de gols por partida
Quantidade de vezes em que o país sede foi campeão
Quantidade de vezes em que o time do Brasil ficou entre uma das 4 primeiras posições
Ano das edições em que o time da França finalizou em terceiro lugar
Quantidade de vitórias por país, classificada em ordem crescente do número de títulos

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida para o que você precisa fazer?

Comment: Eu preciso fazer um programa para cumprir os requisitos acima, estes dados estão em um arquivo CSV que postei junto. Em resumo...preciso entender como faço para realizar essas operações

Comment: Basicamente você pode fazer um loop for e ir armazenando o valor de cada linha que você quer baseado numa condição. Semelhante ao que você fez para a soma. Só não precisa ser tudo na mesma linha. Faz um bloco mesmo de loop for.

Comment: Só precisa saber do que você precisa para calcular o que você quer e armazenar essa informação durante o loop. Ex.: A média você precisa da quantidade de elementos e do somatório. Aí basta armazenar a soma e no final dividir pelo número de vezes que você somou.